# Usbmon module missing?

Tags: usb, kernel

I am trying to monitor the USB traffic in Ubuntu 10.0.4. According to many websites, the usbmon is already included in the kernel, but typing modprobe usbmon. It will return "Can't find module".

Do I have to recompile the usbmon module?

Comment: If you are using 10.04 and later modprobe is meant to be intelligent enough to know when a module is actually built in and not error when trying to modprobe that module.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can tell for sure if your kernel was compiled with USBMON by running:

```
grep CONFIG_USB_MON /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

In my case, I see `CONFIG_USB_MON=y` as the response... This means it's built directly into the kernel instead of as a module. I built my own kernel but to my knowledge, the `.config` used stems from a Maverick kernel.

I don't have a standard Maverick box to test on but my media centre box is just upgrading now. Won't be too long.

My media centre is on Mav now. Still returning `y` so it is built into the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Usbmon is directly compiled in the ubuntu kernel ( not as a module ). I tested on maverick but you can confirm that on 10.04 doing this.

Go to the 'config' folder of your kernel:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-<yourversion>-generic/include/config
```

Search usbmon configuration:

```
grep -rn "CONFIG_USB_MON" *
```

If your output is something like this:

```
auto.conf:1494:CONFIG_USB_MON=y
tristate.conf:1040:CONFIG_USB_MON=Y
```

Then usbmod is already compiled inside your kernel.

Also you can refer to this bug (that was marked as Invalid):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/364085